Use the flow of directus to update field A into the splicing of field B and field C
When I want to create and update a record of [customization], [identifier]=[model_name]+[customization_version]+[fw_version]+[hw_version], how should I do it? The required input is a json, so I am not familiar with it. , I checked the official documentation, but this is still difficult for me.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried syntax like this
{
    "identifier": "data.fw_version"+"data.hw_version"
}

{
    "identifier": "${Pdata.fw_version}"+"${data.hw_version}"
}

but didn't work
